# How to parse data, if it `isKindOfClass([NSString] class)` in Objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

**I'm stuck over here, I'm new to iOS, please help me.**

Right now I've data in my `dict` but of different class format. If it is in `NSDictionary` format then it works well, it parse all data & display it properly.

Now some time my `JSON` returns NSDictionary, &  sometimes it returns NSString.

Bellow is the code, for reading JSON data it is a KindOfClass:`NSDictionary`

```
@interface demoActivityDetails()

@property (strong ,nonatomic) NSArray *activityDescription;

@end

@implementation demoActivityDetails

    - (instancetype)initWithDict:(NSDictionary *)dict{
        self = [super init];

    if (self) {


     if ([dict isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]) {
                NSLog(@"String");
            //I'm stuck over here, don't know how do I parse data if it is NSString class
      }
     else if ([dict isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
                if ([[dict valueForKey:@"demoActivityTypeCode"] valueForKey:@"value"]) {
                    self.demoActivityTypeCode = [[dict valueForKey:@"demoActivityTypeCode"] valueForKey:@"value"];
                }


                if ([[[dict valueForKey:@"cityOfActivity"] valueForKey:@"cityCode"] valueForKey:@"value"]) {
                    self.cityOfOrigin = [[[dict valueForKey:@"cityOfActivity"] valueForKey:@"cityCode"] valueForKey:@"value"];
                }

                if ([[[dict valueForKey:@"cityOfActivity"] valueForKey:@"cityySubdivisionCode"] valueForKey:@"value"]) {
                    self.citySubdivisionCodeArray = [[[dict valueForKey:@"cityOfActivity"] valueForKey:@"citySubdivisionCode"] valueForKey:@"value"];
                }




                if ([dict valueForKey:@"activityDescription"]) {
                    self.activityDescription = [dict  valueForKey:@"activityDescription"];
                }

                if ([self.activityDescription isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]) {

                    if ([self.activityDescription valueForKey:@"languageCode"]) {
                        self.flagsArray = [self.activityDescription valueForKey:@"languageCode"];
                    }

                    if ([self.activityDescription valueForKey:@"value"]) {
                        self.subTitleArray = [self.activityDescription valueForKey:@"value"];
                    }

                    if (self.flagsArray && self.subTitleArray) {

                        self.subTitleWithLangCode  = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithObjects:self.subTitleArray forKeys:self.flagsArray];
                    }

                    if ([self.flagsArray containsObject:@"en"]) {
                        for (int i=0 ; i < self.flagsArray.count; i++ ) {
                            if ([self.flagsArray[i] isEqualToString:@"en"]) {
                                self.subTitle = [self.subTitleArray objectAtIndex:i];
                                self.selectedFlag = [self.flagsArray objectAtIndex:i];
                            }
                        }
                    }else {
                        self.subTitle = [self.subTitleArray firstObject];
                        self.selectedFlag = [self.flagsArray firstObject];
                    }

                }
                else if ([self.activityDescription isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]) {
                    self.subTitle = (NSString *)self.activityDescription;
                }

            }

      }

        }
        return self;
    }

    @end
```

Please somebody help me.

Comment: When you receive data in NSString, is it in a format, like this @"{\"demoActivityTypeCode\":{\"value\":1},\"cityOfActivity\":{\"cityCode:201\"},\"ContractTemplateID\":{\"Content\":65,\"type\":\"text\"}}"

Comment: No, it is similar to json format.

Comment: {
    activityDescription =     {
        languageCode = en;
        value = "Activity Description_en";
    };
    cityOfActivity =     {
        cityCode =         {
            value = 012;
        };
        citySubdivisionCode =         {
            value = "CA";
        };
    };
   demoActivityTypeCode =     {
        value = “SampleText”;
    };
}

Comment: It is similar to this

Answer (score 0):

If the String is in `JSON` format, you can convert it into `NSData` and then use `NSJSONSerialization` to convert data to JSON object(`NSDictionary`, in your case). I think you should introduce different initializers depending on the argument. Also, you should clean up your parsing logic in `initWithDict`. You will be rewarded for checking the type before assigning to references. In case, if the data from backend or wherever, mismatches your parsing code, you can resolve issue gracefully, otherwise it may result in a crash.
I would re-write this class something like this:

```
@interface DemoActivityDetails()

@property (strong ,nonatomic) NSArray *activityDescription;
@property (strong ,nonatomic) NSString *demoActivityTypeCode;
@property (strong ,nonatomic) NSString *cityOfOrigin;
@property (strong ,nonatomic) NSArray<NSString*> *citySubdivisionCodeArray;

@end

@implementation DemoActivityDetails

- (instancetype _Nullable)initWithObject:(id _Nonnull)object {
    if(object == nil) {
        return nil;
    }
    if([object isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]])
        return [self initWithDict:object];
    else if([object isKindOfClass:[NSString class]])
        return [self initWithString:object];
    else
        return nil;
}

- (instancetype _Nullable)initWithString:(NSString* _Nonnull)string {
    if(![string isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]) {
        return nil;
    }
    NSData* data = [string dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    if(!data){
        return nil;
    }
    id json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];
    if(json == nil || ![json isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
        return nil;
    }
    return [self initWithDict:json];
}

- (instancetype _Nullable)initWithDict:(NSDictionary* _Nonnull)dict {
    if(![dict isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
        return nil;
    }
    self = [super init];
    if(self) {
        NSDictionary* demoActivityTypeCodeDict = [dict objectForKey:@"demoActivityTypeCode"];
        if([demoActivityTypeCodeDict isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
            NSString* demoActivityTypeCode = [demoActivityTypeCodeDict objectForKey:@"value"];
            if([demoActivityTypeCode isKindOfClass:[NSString class]])
                self.demoActivityTypeCode = demoActivityTypeCode;
        }

        NSDictionary* cityOfActivityDict = [dict objectForKey:@"cityOfActivity"];
        if([cityOfActivityDict isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
            NSDictionary* cityCodeDict = [cityOfActivityDict objectForKey:@"cityCode"];
            if([cityCodeDict isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
                NSString* cityOrigin = [cityCodeDict objectForKey:@"value"];
                if([cityOrigin isKindOfClass:[NSString class]])
                    self.cityOfOrigin = cityOrigin;
            }
        }

        // you can continue writing code
        // ....

    }
    return self;
}
```

*PS: It is also a norm to not use camel-case for naming the class, instead start the class name from a capital*

Comment: Thanks I'll try out.